# Check for empty arrays in Hasura

Tags: postgresql, graphql, hasura

I have the following Query:

```
query {
  table1(where: {table2: {id: {}}}) {
    id
  }
}
```

There is a relationship between `table1` and `table2` via a foreign key. That is, in `table2` I have a column named `table1_id` and so I can access `table2` from `table1`. I want to query all rows from `table1` that have no related rows in `table2`. That is, if I do the following query:

```
query {
  table1 {
    table2 {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

I want the rows in `table1` where this query returns an empty array. I have tried the following:

```
query {
  table1(where: {table2: {id: {_in: []}}}) {
    id
  }
}
```

And

```
query {
  table1(where: {table2: {id: {_is_null: true}}}) {
    id
  }
}
```

But nothing seems to work (I get back an empty array). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```js
query {
  table1(where: {_not: { table2: {} } }) {
    id
  }
}
```

Should work to return the records from table1 that don't have a relationship with table2

Answer (score 2):

The selected answer is actually incorrect. It should be the following:

```
query {
  table1(where: {_not: { table2: {} } }) {
    id
  }
}
```

Edit: The selected answer is good now :)

Comment: I edited my answer to avoid any confusion. Thanks

Comment: @LeonardoAlves Ah great. I didn't have permission to edit your answer so had to make a separate answer. I reverted the downvote to an upvote!